# WINDOW.CLOSE () JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING IN XPAGES

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

WINDOW.CLOSE () JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING IN XPAGES.

All ready I am tried window. close () but does not work in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Can you put up some code?  I assume that this is csjs rather than ssjs code.

Comment: YOUR CAPS LOCK APPEARS TO BE STUCK, OR YOU'RE SHOUTING AT US. EITHER WAY, PLEASE STOP. Text typed in all CAPS is more difficult to read and comprehend, SHOUTING won't get you help any more quickly, and it's really rude to SHOUT at those you're asking for free help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, I know I have used it but browser security will not allow you to close a window that was not opened by your code in another window.

Make sure your code is in a client side JavaScript event. There is no SSJS window.close (or window anything for that matter).

Howard